# Find all reachable nodes in a graph

Tags: code-golf, graph-theory

You are given a directed graph in an adjacency dictionary format. This can be whatever format is most natural for your language. For instance, in python, this would be a dictionary with  keys of nodes and values which are lists of nodes which that node has an edge to. For instance:

```
G={1: [2, 3], 2: [3], 3: [1], 4:[2]}
```

Be reasonable. A dictionary of frozen sets is not allowed, even if it makes your code shorter. A list of lists is fine, if your language doesn't have dictionaries.

Your task is to implement a function that takes a directed graph and a starting node, and outputs all nodes reachable from the starting node. The output format is also flexible. A return value from a function is fine, so is print, etc.

Test case:

```
G={1: [2, 3], 2: [3], 3: [1], 4:[2]}
s=1

R(G,s)
{1,2,3}
```

Fewest characters wins. I will clarify if needed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Mathematica <s>63 40</s> 37

My earlier submission was incorrect. I had misinterpreted what `ConnectedComponents` returns.  The present approach relies on Belisarius' suggestion to use`VertexOutComponent`. 3 additional chars saved by alephalpha.

The following generates an 11 by 11 adjacency matrix of 0's and 1's, where 1 indicates that the vertex with the row number is connected directly to the vertex corresponding to column number of the cell. (`SeedRandom` ensures that your matrix `a` will match mine.)

```
SeedRandom[21]
a = Array[RandomChoice[{0.9, 0.1} -> {0, 1}] &, {11, 11}];
```

---

### Example

(37 chars)

```
 AdjacencyGraph@a~VertexOutComponent~4
```

> {4, 1, 7, 8, 9, 3}

---

### Verifying

The directed graph displays how to reach vertices `{1, 7, 8, 9, 3}` from vertex 4.

```
AdjacencyGraph[a, ImagePadding -> 30, VertexLabels -> "Name"]
```

[image: graph]

Comment: Not sure. Methinks it's `m = {{0, 1, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 1, 0}}; ConnectedComponents[AdjacencyGraph[m, DirectedEdges -> True], 1]`

Comment: I'll check and get back to you.

Comment: Nope. Mine is wrong. Not sure about yours.

Comment: This seems to work: `m = {{0, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 1, 0}}; VertexOutComponent[AdjacencyGraph@m, 3, Infinity]`. The `DirectedEdges -> True` isn't needed.

Comment: I forgot about `VertexOutComponent`.  Would you like to post?

Comment: Nah, I think one Mma answer per Q is enough. Please be my guest to use the code if that fits you :)

Comment: Is the `∞` here necessary?

Comment: Apparently \[Infinity] is not needed. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

## Python 2.7 - <strike>80</strike> 65

```python
def R(G,s):
 k=a={s}
 while k:a=a|k;k|=set(G[k.pop()])-a
 print a
```

Answer (score 4):

#### GolfScript, <strike>27</strike> 24 characters

```
{:G,{G{1$&},{)||}/}*}:C;
```

This code implements the operator `C` which takes starting node and graph on the stack and leaves a list of reachable notes on the stack after execution.

*Example ([online](http://golfscript.apphb.com/?c=ezpHLHtHezEkJn0seyl8fH0vfSp9OkM7CgpbMV0gW1sxIFsyIDNdXVsyIFszXV1bMyBbMV1dWzQgWzJdXV0gQyBwCgoK&run=true)):*

```
[1] [[1 [2 3]][2 [3]][3 [1]][4 [2]]] C
# returns [1 2 3]
```

Comment: You can get a reasonable saving with a filter. The best I've got so far is to replace the inner loop with `G{1$&},{~||}/`

Comment: @PeterTaylor Thank you. I was working on a different approach (`.{{&}+G?)||}/`) which has the same character count but I find your's a bit nicer.

Answer (score 2):

## J - <strike>19</strike> 15 char

J doesn't have a dictionary type, and is generally garbage with representing things the way people are used to in other languages. This is a bit idiosyncratic with how it represents things, but that's because J and graphs don't blend well, and not because I'm looking for optimal ways of representing directed graphs. But even if it doesn't count, I think it's a concise, interesting algorithm.

```
~.@(],;@:{~)^:_
```

This is a function which takes a graph on the left and a list of nodes to start with on the right.

Graphs are lists of boxed lists, and the nodes are indices into the list that represents the graph. J indexes from zero, so nodes are nonnegative integers, but you can skip 0 and pretend to have 1-based indexing by using an empty list (`''`) in the 0 place. (Indented lines are input to the J console, lines flush with the margin are output.)

```
   2 4;1 2 4;0;0 2;1   NB. {0: [2, 4], 1: [1, 2, 4], 2: [0], 3: [0, 2], 4:[1]}
+---+-----+-+---+-+
|2 4|1 2 4|0|0 2|1|
+---+-----+-+---+-+
   '';2 3;3;1;2        NB. {1: [2, 3], 2: [3], 3: [1], 4:[2]}
++---+-+-+-+
||2 3|3|1|2|
++---+-+-+-+
   '';'';2;9;1 7 8 9;3 6;4 8;7;'';3;'';7   NB. the big Mathematica example
+++-+-+-------+---+---+-++-++-+
|||2|9|1 7 8 9|3 6|4 8|7||3||7|
+++-+-+-------+---+---+-++-++-+
```

Lists of numbers are just space-separated lists of numbers. In general a scalar (just one number in a row) is not the same as a one-item list, but I use only safe operations that end up promoting scalars to one-item lists, so everything's cool.

The function explained (supposing we invoke as `graph ~.@(],;@:{~)^:_ nodes`):

- `{~` - For each node in `nodes`, take the list of adjacent nodes from `graph`.
- `;@:` - Turn the list of adjacencies into a list of nodes.
- `],` - Prepend `nodes` to this list.
- `~.@` - Throw out any duplicates.
- `^:_` - Repeat this procedure with the same `graph` until it results in no change to the right hand argument, i.e. there are no new nodes to discover.

The verb in action:

```
   ('';2 3;3;1;2) ~.@(],;@:{~)^:_ (1)           NB. example in question
1 2 3
   f =: ~.@(],;@:{~)^:_                         NB. name for convenience
   (2 4;1 2 4;0;0 2;1) f 2
2 0 4 1
   ('';'';2;9;1 7 8 9;3 6;4 8;7;'';3;'';7) f 4  NB. Mathematica example
4 1 7 8 9 3
```

If you don't like this graph representation, here's a couple quick verbs for converting to/from adjacency matrices.

```
   a=:<@#i.@#        NB. adj.mat. to graph
   mat=:0,0,.0 1 1 0,0 0 1 0,1 0 0 0,:0 1 0 0
   mat               NB. adj.mat. for {1:[2,3],2:[3],3:[1],4:[2]}
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 1 1 0
0 0 0 1 0
0 1 0 0 0
0 0 1 0 0
   a mat
++---+-+-+-+
||2 3|3|1|2|
++---+-+-+-+
   A=:+/@:=&>/i.@#   NB. graph to adj.mat.
   A a mat
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 1 1 0
0 0 0 1 0
0 1 0 0 0
0 0 1 0 0
```

For anyone wondering why the graph is the left argument to the verb, it's because that's the general convention in J: control information on the left, data on the right. Consider list search, `list i. item`, and the sequential machine dyad, `machine ;: input`.

Answer (score 2):

## [APL (Dyalog Extended)](https://github.com/abrudz/dyalog-apl-extended), 7 bytes

```apl
⌂search
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNrShJzUtJTfn//1FPU3FqYlFyxv@0R20THvX2PepqPrTe@FHbxEd9U4ODnIFkiIdn8P/0osSCDKAKDSMFY00NIDLU1DDS5AILK6QpGMJZRnCWCQA)

A library function that does the job. Takes the graph on its left and the start node on its right, and gives the list of reachable nodes using breadth-first search.

Since APL has neither sets nor dicts, the closest input format is a nested vector of vectors like `(2 3)(3)(1)(2)`. And, just by coincidence, Dyalog APL's [graph library](http://dfns.dyalog.com/n_Graphs.htm) uses this exact format as the representation for graphs.

Because a built-in is boring, here is another solution without it (which is still short):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 10 [bytes](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)

```apl
(∪/⊢,⌷⍨)⍣≡
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///X@NRxyr9R12LdB71bH/Uu0LzUe/iR50L/6c9apvwqLfvUVfzofXGj9omPuqbGhzkDCRDPDyD/6cXJRZkAFVoGCkYa2oAkaGmhpEmF1hYIU3BEM4ygrNMAA)

Same input format and left/right argument order. Returns the same result, but nested once. Keeping one level of nesting throughout the `⍣≡`-loop gives several advantages in terms of golfing.

#### How it works

```apl
(∪/⊢,⌷⍨)⍣≡  ⍝ Tacit infix function. left←graph, right←node
(      )⍣≡  ⍝ Repeat until the right arg converges...
     ⌷⍨     ⍝ Simulate following all possible edges from input node(s)
            ⍝ which gives a vector of nested vectors of nodes
   ⊢,       ⍝ Prepend the (nested) list of initial nodes
 ∪/         ⍝ Reduce by set union;
            ⍝ preserve the order of existing nodes by
            ⍝ having the input on the left end

Example run:
  graph←(2 3)(3)(1)(2) ⋄ node←1
  First iteration:
       ⌷⍨     ⊂2 3  ⍝ extract index 1 of graph
     ⊢,       1(2 3)
   ∪/         ⊂1 2 3
  (      )⍣≡  Converged? No.
  Second iteration:
       ⌷⍨     (2 3)(3)(1)  ⍝ extract indices 1, 2, 3 of graph
     ⊢,       (1 2 3)(2 3)(3)(1)
   ∪/         ⊂1 2 3
  (      )⍣≡  Converged? Yes, stop.
```

Answer (score 1):

### Python 2.7 (using networkx) - 71

```
from networkx import*
single_source_shortest_path(DiGraph(G),s).keys()
```

**Sample Run**

```
>>> G={1: [2, 3], 2: [3], 3: [1], 4:[2]}
>>> s=1
>>> from networkx import*
>>> single_source_shortest_path(DiGraph(G),s).keys()
[1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: networkx is not really core Python.

Comment: @isaacg: I do not see any restriction to use core Python. It is an accepted practice in this forum to use libraries unless it is explicitly restricted. So I disagree with your comment and downvote.

Comment: Is that so? I must have been unclear on the accepted practice of the forum. I will remove my downvote at the next opportunity.

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ECMAScript 6) - 70 Characters

```
f=(G,s)=>{y=Set([s]);y.forEach(x=>G[x].forEach(z=>y.add(z)));return y}
```

**Test**

```
G={1: [2, 3], 2: [3], 3: [1], 4:[2]}
s=1
f(G,s)
```

Returns a set containing:

```
1,2,3
```

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica, 29 chars

```
{s}//.l_List:>(l⋃##&@@(l/.G))
```

#### Example:

```
G = {1 -> {2, 3}, 2 -> {3}, 3 -> {1}, 4 -> {2}}; s = 1;
{s}//.l_List:>(l⋃##&@@(l/.G))
```

> {1, 2, 3}

Comment: This is an awesome solution. I don't understand Mathematica, though. Could you explain?

Answer (score 1):

## Python – <s>54</s> 52 + 7 + 7

```python
def R(G,s,A):
    A|={s}
    for n in set(G[s])-A:R(G,n,A)
```

`R` needs to be called with an empty set as an additional argument. This set contains the output, when `R` has finished. Example of usage:

```python
G = {1: [2, 3], 2: [3], 3: [1], 4:[2]}
A=set()
R(G,1,A)
print A
```

If you consider this way of output cheating, keep in mind that it’s very normal in C, for example. Anyway, you may want to charge 7 additional chars for the intialisation of the empty set (`A=set()`) and 7 for the `print` line.

Comment: I would allow this method, but charge you six characters for the empty set - A={[]} - and seven characters for the print A line, for a total of 67 characters. YMMV, though.

Comment: @isaacg: I accept the charge for the empty set, but why the charge for printing? Would you also charge this for a function, which returns the set/list/… in a “regular” manner?

Comment: A return value would not be charged for. Eh - it's rather borderline, I could see the A value being free. The issue I see is that you essentially just saved the output to a variable, not returned or output it.

Answer (score 1):

## K4 , 12 bytes

The code is:

```
{?,/x,G x}/1
```

Here's an example of its use:

```
  G:1 2 3 4!(2 3;3;1;2)
  {?,/x,G x}/1
1 2 3
  H:(!12)!(();();2;9;1 7 8 9;3 6;4 8;7;();3;();7)
  {?,/x,H x}/4
4 1 7 8 9 3
```

input is a dictionary from int to int or list of int

the basic op is `G s`, retrieve the child nodes for `s`

this is then stuffed into the built-in convergence operator `/`

the rest is to, at each stage, prepend the parent node, flatten the results down to a vector, and dedupe them -- this is needed to make the answer actually converge

btw, for an extra three characters, you can have *all* the reachability lists:

```
  {G(?,/,)'G x}/G
1 2 3 4!(2 3 1;3 1 2;1 2 3;2 3 1)
  {H(?,/,)'H x}/H
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11!(();();,2;9 3;1 7 8 9 3;3 6 9 4 8 1 7;4 8 1 7 9 3;,7;();3 9;();,7)
```

this is the same general idea, applied to the basic op of `G G`

Comment: This should be the accepted answer...

Answer (score 0):

### Python, 72 chars

```
def R(G,s):
 r=[s]
 for i in G:r+=sum((G[x]for x in r),[])
 print set(r)
```

Terribly inefficient because nodes can appear in `r` multiple times.  Fortunately, not a judging criterion.

Comment: You can shave 2 characters and make it even more inefficient by changing the empty list to r and += to +.

Comment: I mean += to =.

Comment: You can shave another character by changing the for loop to and exec statement and one-lining it: `def R(g,s):r=[s];exec'r=sum((G[x]for x in r),r);'*len(G);print set(r)`

Answer (score 0):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 64 bytes

```hs
import Data.List
n#v=nub$id=<<length n`take`iterate(>>=(n!!))[v]
```

Takes input as a zero-based list of lists, [try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcNBCoMwEAXQvaf4ogsFKbVr46rL3iAEnNKhDsZR4tTrpy28N9OxcIw5y7pvyXAno8tDDiu0Op1@nrW83DBE1rfN0Mlo4UmMExk34@gaLcu29WfIK4nCYU@ihroAvO@7W@j8/08fAipc8xc)

#### Explanation / Ungolfed

The term `vertices >>= (adjacencyList !!)` takes a list of `vertices`, looks up all reachable vertices of them and returns them as a list.

So we repeatedly do this starting with the input vertex `[v]`

```hs
                       iterate(>>=(n!!))[v]
```

take as many elements from that list as there are nodes in the graph

```hs
         length n`take`
```

concatenate the result

```hs
    id=<<
```

and finally remove all the duplicates

```hs
nub$
```

.

Answer (score 0):

## Java 10, 130 characters

A curried lambda that takes the graph as a `Map<Integer, List<Integer>>` and an `int` start node. Output is returned as a `Set<Integer>`.

```java
import java.util.*;
```

```java
g->s->{var o=new TreeSet();o.add(s);for(var x:g.keySet())for(var n:new TreeSet(o))o.addAll(g.get(n));return o;}
```

[Try It Online](https://tio.run/##lVHLbtswEDzLX7FHMpWJOulJsgXkUrRAc3Juhg@sTdF0KJIgKbeGoG93lrKCKEZboBc@hjM7u8MjP/H5cf9yUY2zPsIR76yNSrO7cjZz7U@tdrDTPAR44spAN8tGMEQecauV4Xoiq1uzi8oa9nU8LN/fnrhbfjdRSOHzieSHCvENr6r8n8X@IF@LibqCGlYXOa/CvOpO3INdGfELnr0QyCO0tIzv9yTQsraeJMLvQrIXcR5e6RtoiqnKUjrIHrUmkklEDKWlF7H1BmzZXzLM6iaXk1V7aDAyso5eGbnZAvcy0JRg9p@RgPTcHWAFqal30jceDklf4VhYVJmIJjhKGJlXoFvkcJ/DQw5f@vKD9wcTZJ64TlLyVwadmD96z8@BhegFbwjWzZLlyN1sk3GXbPscumFZpOW@75FKE5013JHbekXBQzK9MqId0JuGNtsi/U6ipHnwy4DgqKCw988lbsshBKaFkfGQgE8rWFyDz4YkmWsjSZyN2ubD2HgYMkzdrc8hiobZNjKHPxe1ITXjzukzGdR0vCxokvSz/vIK)

This carries out a slightly stupid breadth-first search just past a maximum possible non-cyclical path length (the number of graph nodes).

Answer (score 0):

### Clojure, 52 bytes

```
#(nth(iterate(fn[A](set(mapcat % A)))[%2])(count %))
```

This implicitly assumes that all nodes have outgoing vertices.

### <s>54 bytes</s>

```
#(loop[A[%2]B[]](if(= A B)A(recur(set(mapcat % A))A)))
```

The nifty part is the `(mapcat % A)`, which uses the input argument `{1 [2, 3], 2 [3], 3 [1], 4 [2]}` as a function (given a key it returns the corresponding value) and concatenates all the ids together. Then it is just a matter of iterating this procedure until we have converged.