# Count the terminal cycles of a directed graph

Tags: code-golf, graph-theory

### Task

You must write a program or function in the language of your choice which accurately counts the number of terminal cycles of a simple directed graph.

This particular kind of directed graph is represented as an array of n integers, each with an independently-chosen random value between 1 and n (or 0 and n-1, if your language counts from 0).  The graph can be thought of as arrows pointing from one index (node) to an index which matches the value found at the starting index.

Your function must be capable of accepting large graphs, up to n=1024, or any smaller integer size.

### Example

Consider this graph for n=10:

```
[9, 7, 8, 10, 2, 6, 3, 10, 6, 8]
```

Index 1 contains a 9, so there's an arrow from index 1 to index 9.  Index 9 contains a 6, so there's an arrow 9 -> 6.  Index 6 contains 6, which is a terminal cycle, pointing back to itself.

Index 2 contains a 7.  Index 7 contains a 3.  Index 3 contains an 8.  Index 8 contains a 10.  Index 10 contains an 8, so that's a second terminal cycle (8 -> 10 -> 8 -> 10, etc.).

Index 4 -> 10, which enters the second terminal cycle.  Likewise, index 5 -> 2 -> 7 -> 3 -> 8, which is also part of the second terminal cycle.

At this point, all indices (nodes) have been checked, all paths have been followed, and two unique terminal cycles are identified.  Therefore, the function should **return 2**, since that is the number of terminal cycles in this directed graph.

### Scoring

Aim for the smallest code, but make sure it counts terminal cycles correctly.  Shortest code after 1 week wins.

### Test Cases

Here's are some test cases to check the correctness of your code.  If your language counts array indices starting from 0, you must of course subtract 1 from the value of each array element, to prevent an out-of-bound index.

n=32, 5 cycles:

```
[8, 28, 14, 8, 2, 1, 13, 15, 30, 17, 9, 8, 18, 19, 30, 3, 8, 25, 23, 12, 6, 7, 19, 24, 17, 7, 21, 20, 29, 15, 32, 32]
```

n=32, 4 cycles:

```
[20, 31, 3, 18, 18, 18, 8, 12, 25, 10, 10, 19, 3, 9, 18, 1, 13, 5, 18, 23, 20, 26, 16, 22, 4, 16, 19, 31, 21, 32, 15, 22]
```

n=32, 3 cycles:

```
[28, 13, 17, 14, 4, 31, 11, 4, 22, 6, 32, 1, 13, 15, 7, 19, 10, 28, 9, 22, 5, 26, 17, 8, 6, 13, 7, 10, 9, 30, 23, 25]
```

n=32, 2 cycles:

```
[25, 23, 22, 6, 24, 3, 1, 21, 6, 18, 20, 4, 8, 5, 16, 10, 15, 32, 26, 25, 27, 14, 13, 12, 9, 9, 29, 8, 13, 31, 32, 1]
```

n=32, 1 cycle:

```
[6, 21, 15, 14, 22, 12, 5, 32, 29, 3, 22, 23, 6, 16, 20, 2, 16, 25, 9, 22, 13, 2, 19, 20, 26, 19, 32, 3, 32, 19, 28, 16]
```

n=32, 1 cycle:

```
[8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

n=1024, 6 cycles:

```
[239, 631, 200, 595, 178, 428, 582, 191, 230, 551, 223, 61, 564, 463, 568, 527, 143, 403, 154, 236, 928, 650, 14, 931, 236, 170, 910, 782, 861, 464, 378, 748, 468, 779, 440, 396, 467, 630, 451, 130, 694, 167, 594, 115, 671, 853, 612, 238, 464, 771, 825, 471, 167, 653, 561, 337, 585, 986, 79, 506, 192, 873, 184, 617, 4, 259, 4, 662, 623, 694, 859, 6, 346, 431, 181, 703, 823, 140, 635, 90, 559, 689, 118, 117, 130, 248, 931, 767, 840, 158, 696, 275, 610, 217, 989, 640, 363, 91, 129, 399, 105, 770, 870, 800, 429, 473, 119, 908, 481, 337, 504, 45, 1011, 684, 306, 126, 215, 729, 771, 5, 302, 992, 380, 824, 868, 205, 807, 917, 407, 759, 181, 640, 685, 795, 258, 180, 900, 20, 773, 546, 866, 564, 761, 632, 895, 968, 980, 651, 225, 676, 18, 685, 784, 208, 227, 3, 267, 852, 57, 487, 566, 633, 849, 309, 543, 145, 575, 811, 621, 560, 492, 24, 665, 66, 851, 168, 262, 259, 754, 481, 565, 768, 172, 1012, 241, 3, 370, 985, 389, 82, 779, 744, 829, 836, 249, 975, 909, 840, 226, 867, 499, 192, 909, 972, 735, 252, 785, 545, 486, 186, 1011, 89, 939, 649, 110, 119, 185, 836, 717, 545, 938, 621, 946, 94, 363, 721, 177, 747, 59, 819, 146, 283, 821, 547, 654, 941, 755, 18, 449, 367, 499, 944, 62, 553, 435, 344, 900, 25, 251, 920, 902, 99, 326, 98, 495, 385, 929, 865, 327, 725, 674, 33, 173, 429, 873, 558, 90, 460, 366, 543, 583, 954, 792, 213, 536, 670, 49, 738, 802, 1015, 23, 915, 119, 263, 307, 601, 474, 971, 826, 613, 446, 37, 145, 894, 901, 307, 906, 886, 990, 89, 798, 384, 487, 822, 354, 768, 902, 163, 179, 134, 920, 439, 619, 215, 94, 709, 744, 366, 543, 349, 347, 2, 438, 141, 486, 19, 998, 500, 857, 955, 932, 1, 587, 195, 646, 550, 887, 626, 400, 348, 154, 808, 678, 873, 186, 282, 168, 993, 722, 56, 345, 5, 226, 328, 22, 894, 658, 264, 13, 803, 791, 359, 217, 997, 168, 578, 952, 734, 964, 898, 659, 628, 980, 15, 31, 439, 13, 875, 687, 1004, 1023, 165, 642, 561, 897, 711, 124, 404, 346, 723, 774, 352, 784, 276, 395, 14, 443, 343, 153, 510, 590, 172, 215, 130, 106, 295, 906, 133, 758, 483, 898, 391, 760, 702, 972, 721, 611, 592, 1001, 724, 934, 59, 831, 171, 253, 869, 431, 538, 20, 648, 76, 351, 103, 33, 385, 852, 437, 470, 95, 434, 408, 430, 994, 366, 706, 809, 532, 161, 388, 668, 245, 965, 365, 913, 471, 927, 245, 256, 805, 540, 380, 995, 446, 657, 545, 573, 955, 499, 322, 949, 635, 401, 185, 421, 626, 534, 429, 930, 633, 563, 348, 626, 518, 682, 233, 775, 444, 42, 199, 57, 271, 683, 397, 883, 620, 768, 8, 331, 497, 19, 340, 900, 919, 497, 276, 78, 252, 164, 764, 927, 242, 270, 759, 824, 945, 886, 262, 59, 439, 217, 720, 519, 862, 626, 326, 339, 589, 16, 565, 947, 604, 144, 87, 520, 256, 240, 336, 685, 361, 998, 805, 678, 24, 980, 203, 818, 855, 85, 276, 822, 183, 266, 347, 8, 663, 620, 147, 189, 497, 128, 357, 855, 507, 275, 420, 755, 131, 469, 672, 926, 859, 156, 127, 986, 489, 803, 433, 622, 951, 83, 862, 108, 192, 167, 862, 242, 519, 574, 358, 549, 119, 630, 60, 925, 414, 479, 330, 927, 94, 767, 562, 919, 1011, 999, 908, 113, 932, 632, 403, 309, 838, 341, 179, 708, 847, 472, 907, 537, 516, 992, 944, 615, 778, 801, 413, 653, 690, 393, 452, 394, 596, 545, 591, 136, 109, 942, 546, 57, 626, 61, 587, 862, 829, 988, 965, 781, 849, 843, 815, 60, 928, 784, 388, 341, 491, 565, 83, 110, 164, 38, 1024, 859, 297, 520, 327, 733, 699, 631, 78, 178, 671, 895, 818, 637, 99, 425, 933, 248, 299, 333, 144, 323, 105, 849, 942, 767, 265, 72, 204, 547, 934, 916, 304, 919, 273, 396, 665, 452, 423, 471, 641, 675, 60, 388, 97, 963, 902, 321, 826, 476, 782, 723, 99, 735, 893, 565, 175, 141, 70, 918, 659, 935, 492, 751, 261, 362, 849, 593, 924, 590, 982, 876, 73, 993, 767, 441, 70, 875, 640, 567, 920, 321, 46, 938, 377, 905, 303, 736, 182, 626, 899, 512, 894, 744, 254, 984, 325, 694, 6, 367, 532, 432, 133, 938, 74, 967, 725, 87, 502, 946, 708, 122, 887, 256, 595, 169, 101, 828, 696, 897, 961, 376, 910, 82, 144, 967, 885, 89, 114, 215, 187, 38, 873, 125, 522, 884, 947, 962, 45, 585, 644, 476, 710, 839, 486, 634, 431, 475, 979, 877, 18, 226, 656, 573, 3, 29, 743, 508, 544, 252, 254, 388, 873, 70, 640, 918, 93, 508, 853, 609, 333, 378, 172, 875, 617, 167, 771, 375, 503, 221, 624, 67, 655, 465, 272, 278, 161, 840, 52, 1016, 909, 567, 544, 234, 339, 463, 621, 951, 962, 1019, 383, 523, 279, 780, 838, 984, 999, 29, 897, 564, 762, 753, 393, 205, 31, 150, 490, 156, 796, 586, 676, 773, 465, 489, 1024, 433, 214, 701, 480, 604, 280, 241, 563, 943, 911, 12, 400, 261, 883, 999, 207, 618, 141, 959, 767, 978, 461, 992, 982, 272, 143, 404, 645, 331, 348, 783, 698, 827, 82, 145, 536, 449, 852, 750, 789, 413, 913, 420, 14, 499, 285, 533, 223, 75, 591, 994, 884, 237, 63, 411, 563, 611, 801, 173, 759, 278, 318, 772, 1018, 48, 440, 333, 611, 834, 423, 583, 22, 716, 393, 794, 83, 83, 864, 859, 600, 525, 808, 569, 95, 952, 852, 567, 651, 2, 984, 906, 992, 747, 602, 143, 547, 1008, 940, 245, 633, 378, 193, 771, 965, 648, 437, 873, 591, 664, 271, 777, 274, 742, 68, 429, 825, 144, 55, 272, 279, 6, 400, 485, 66, 311, 663, 441, 23, 988, 726, 48, 624, 302, 617, 120, 653, 810, 641, 142]
```

Comment: Sure, here's a big fat n=1024 test case.  Hopefully I didn't butcher it while packaging it for Stack Exchange.

Comment: Clarify: If the language uses zero-based arrays, then the numbers in the array will all be zero-based, or not?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.  The numbers in the array will always point to a valid array index.  I used the 'human style' counting method of starting from 1 because that's what my language uses, and I didn't want to screw up my examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### GolfScript, 25 characters

```
:I{{I=.}I.+,*]I,>$0=}%.&,
```

Same approach as [Keith Randall](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/67/keith-randall)'s solution but in GolfScript. Note that GolfScript has zero-indexed arrays. [Online tester](http://golfscript.apphb.com/?c=O1s4IDYgNyA5IDEgNSAyIDkgNSA3XQoKOkl7e0k9Ln1JLissKl1JLD4kMD19JS4mLAo%3D&run=true).

```
:I        # Assign input to variable I
{         # Foreach item in I
  {I=.}   # Code block: take the n-th list item
  I.+,*   # Iterate the code block 2*len(I) times
  ]       # and gather result in an array
  I,>     # Take last len(I) items
  $0=     # Get minimum
}%
.&        # Take unique items
,         # Count
```

Comment: Hard to believe so much is accomplished with so little code.

Comment: That's impressively short.

Answer (score 5):

## Mathematica 69

### Code

This finds the number of graph components.

```
f@l_ := Length@WeaklyConnectedComponents@Graph@Thread[Range@Length@l -> l]
```

---

The first test case:

```
v = {8, 28, 14, 8, 2, 1, 13, 15, 30, 17, 9, 8, 18, 19, 30, 3, 8, 25, 23, 12, 6, 7, 19, 24, 17, 7, 21, 20, 29, 15, 32, 32}
f[v]
```

> 5

---

### Analysis

Make a list of directed edges between indices, (using example 1).

```
Thread[Range@Length@v -> v
```

> {1 -> 8, 2 -> 28, 3 -> 14, 4 -> 8, 5 -> 2, 6 -> 1, 7 -> 13, 8 -> 15, 
>    9 -> 30, 10 -> 17, 11 -> 9, 12 -> 8, 
>   13 -> 18, 14 -> 19, 15 -> 30, 
>    16 -> 3, 17 -> 8, 18 -> 25, 19 -> 23, 20 -> 12, 21 -> 6, 22 -> 7, 
>    23 -> 19, 24 -> 24, 25 -> 17, 26 -> 7, 27 -> 21, 28 -> 20, 29 -> 29, 
>    30 -> 15, 31 -> 32, 32 -> 32}

---

`Graph` draws a graph showing the graph components.

`ImagePadding` and `VertexLabels`
are used here to show the indices.

```
Graph[Thread[Range[Length@v] -> v], ImagePadding -> 30, VertexLabels -> "Name"]
```

### [image: components]

`WeaklyConnectedComponents` returns the list of vertices for each component.

`Length` returns the number of components.

```
c = WeaklyConnectedComponents[g]
Length[c]
```

> {{17, 10, 25, 8, 18, 1, 4, 12, 15, 13, 6, 20, 30, 7, 21, 28, 9, 22, 
>     26, 27, 2, 11, 5}, {14, 3, 19, 16, 23}, {32, 31}, {24}, {29}}
>
> 5

---

### Timing of sample list with 1024 elements:

Timing:  0.002015 sec

```
f[z] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {0.002015, 6}

---

Just for fun, here's a picture of the final test case, graphed.  I omitted the vertex labels; there are too many.

```
Graph[Thread[Range[Length@z] -> z], GraphLayout -> "RadialEmbedding"]
```

[image: graph z]

Comment: Very concise, despite the 25-character function name.  This may prove hard to beat.  Also, it looks rather like a Choose Your Own Adventure story.

Comment: `WeaklyConnectedComponents` is very verbose.  But it does a lot of work.  (One should never underestimate J and similar languages for conciseness.  )

Comment: At some point, I suspect Wolfram will run out of ideas and just start turning Stack Exchange answers into library functions, is order to justify new releases.

Comment: Yes, I see what you mean.  There are literally thousands of functions built into Mathematica at present.  What's strange is that they work together so well.

Comment: That initial framework of expression-rewriting was a damned good idea.  Now if only they'd implement multiple levels of undo...

Comment: One may save 11 bytes with `Tr[EdgeCycleMatrix@Graph@Thread[Range@Length@l->l]!]` to count the cycles. Also, the `Graph@` can be omitted to save 6 more bytes, but I don't remember if this was already the case in 2014.

Answer (score 2):

### Python, <strike>132</strike> 116 chars

```
def T(V):
 n=len(V);r=range(n);s={}
 for i in r:
    p=[i]
    for k in r+r:p+=[V[p[-1]]]
    s[min(p[n:])]=1
 return len(s)
```

For each index, we follows edges for n hops, which guarantees we are in a terminal cycle.  We then follow n more hops and find the minimum index in that cycle.  The total number of terminal cycles is then just the number of different minima we find.

Comment: I like this method.  Perhaps there's a way to combine 'i in r' loops?

Comment: Sad that you can't `#define F for i in r` in Python, C(++)-style... :)

Answer (score 1):

In Python:

```py
def c(l):
    if(l==[]):
        return 0
    elif (l[-1]==len(l)):
        return c(l[:-1])+1
    else:
        return c([[x,l[-1]][x==len(l)] for x in l[:-1]])
```

Comment: This is code-golf. Please add the number of bytes in your submission. You might want to remove unnecessary whitespace.

Comment: As well as unnecessary parentheses. They are not needed in the `if` conditions.

Comment: `c=lambda l:0 if l==[] else c(l[:-1])+1 if l[-1]==len(l) else c([[x,l[-1]][x==len(l)] for x in l[:-1]])` is better: 102 bytes.

Answer (score 1):

## J - <strike>61</strike> 53 char

This one was a doozy.

```
#@([:#/.~[:+./ .*"1/~@e.<~.@(],;@:{~)^:_&.>])@:(<@<:)
```

The `<@<:` turn the list into a J graph, which looks like a list of boxes, and the box at index `i` contains all the nodes that node `i` connects to. J indexes from zero, so we use `<:` to decrement everything by one before boxing with `<`.

```
   (<@<:) 9 7 8 10 2 6 3 10 6 8
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
|8|6|7|9|1|5|2|9|5|7|
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
```

The `<~.@(],;@:{~)^:_&.>]` turns each node into a list of all the nodes that can be reached from it. The `<...&.>]` is responsible for making this happen to each node, and the `~.@(],;@:{~)^:_` actually comes from [a J golf of this 'nodes reachable' task](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/26103/5138) I did a couple of weeks ago.

```
   (<~.@(],;@:{~)^:_&.>])@:(<@<:) 9 7 8 10 2 6 3 10 6 8
+---+-------+---+---+---------+-+-----+---+-+---+
|8 5|6 2 7 9|7 9|9 7|1 6 2 7 9|5|2 7 9|9 7|5|7 9|
+---+-------+---+---+---------+-+-----+---+-+---+
```

`e.` performs an interesting task. If the "reachability" closure of the graph (the version of the graph such that if there are directed edges X→Y and Y→Z we add the edge X→Z.) has N nodes and E edges, then `e.` on this graph makes a boolean matrix of N rows and E columns, with a True if the corresponding node shares a reachable node with this edge. Confusing, but bear with me.

```
   ([:e.<~.@(],;@:{~)^:_&.>])@:(<@<:) 9 7 8 10 2 6 3 10 6 8
1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0
0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1
0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 1
0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 1
0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1
0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0
0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1
0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 1
0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0
0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 1
```

Next, we have to find the number of terminal cycles, i.e. the number of groups that share Trues amongst their columns. We want to make sort of a multiplication table of the rows (`"1/~`), and we use a kind of inner product as the multiplication, one that ANDs pairwise and then ORs all the results together (`+./ .*`). The resulting matrix is a square table with a True in each position that two rows share at least one column between them.

```
   ([:+./ .*"1/~@e.<~.@(],;@:{~)^:_&.>])@:(<@<:) 9 7 8 10 2 6 3 10 6 8
1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0
0 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1
0 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1
0 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1
0 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1
1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0
0 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1
0 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1
1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0
0 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1
```

Now all that's left to do is to check how many different kinds of row patterns there are. So we do exactly that: group together rows of the same kind (`/.~`), report the number in each group (`#`), and then take the number of groups (`#@`).

```
   #@([:#/.~[:+./ .*"1/~@e.<~.@(],;@:{~)^:_&.>])@:(<@<:) 9 7 8 10 2 6 3 10 6 8
2
```

Usage on other examples:

```
   tcc =: #@([:#/.~[:+./ .*"1/~@e.<~.@(],;@:{~)^:_&.>])@:(<@<:)  NB. name
   tcc 8 28 14 8 2 1 13 15 30 17 9 8 18 19 30 3 8 25 23 12 6 7 19 24 17 7 21 20 29 15 32 32
5
   tcc 20 31 3 18 18 18 8 12 25 10 10 19 3 9 18 1 13 5 18 23 20 26 16 22 4 16 19 31 21 32 15 22
4
   tcc 6 21 15 14 22 12 5 32 29 3 22 23 6 16 20 2 16 25 9 22 13 2 19 20 26 19 32 3 32 19 28 16
1
   tcc tentwentyfour  NB. the 1024-node example
6
```

Unfortunately the 1024 element case now takes a really long time to terminate. The previous version `<:@#@((#~0={.+/@:*"1])^:a:)@e.@(~.@(],;@:{~)^:_&.>~<)@:(<@<:)` (61 char) took a little over a second to do this.

Comment: Ah yes, the good old e. function, I should have known.  o_O  I'm getting lightheahed looking at your code.  Well done.

Answer (score 0):

## Python (96)

Very, very, very, very based on user2228078's answer, as it works exactly the same, but is more golfed:

```
c=lambda l:(1+c(l[:-1])if l[-1]==len(l)else c([[x,l[-1]][x==len(l)]for x in l[:-1]]))if l else 0
```

(Technical question: should a golfing of someone elses answer be community wiki?)

Comment: You have my blessing to plagiarize.  Let it be a community effort.

Comment: @user2790167 Sure, there ya go ;)

Answer (score 0):

## Python <strike>(89)</strike> (87)

```py
def c(G):
 u=i=0
 for _ in G:
  j=i;i+=1
  while j>=0:G[j],j=~i,G[j]
  u+=j==~i
 return u
```

The main idea is to start at each node at turn and walk along the path from it, marking each node we visit with a label unique to the node we started at. If we ever hit a marked node, we stop walking, and check if the marking is the one corresponding to our starting node. If it is we must have walked a loop, so we increment the count of cycles by one.

In the code, `u` is the cycle counter, `i` is the starting node, `j` is the current node we're walking. The label corresponding to starting node `i` is its bit-complement `~i` which is always negative. We mark a node by pointing it to that value, overwriting whatever node it actually pointed to (being careful to walk to that node before it's forgotten).

We know we've hit a marked node when we walk to a negative-value "node" immediately afterwards. We check if that negative value is the current label to see whether we've walked a cycle. Since each node we walk is effectively deleted, each cycle will only be walked once.

It saves characters to count up `i` manually with a dummy loop variable `_` then as `for i in range(len(G))`. Python lists are 0-indexed. If they were instead 1-indexed, we could save two characters by writing `j=i=i+1` to have `i` and `j` be 1 for the first loop, and 
write `j>0` in place of `j>=0`.

### Edit:

We can save two characters by iterating `i` over the elements of the list rather than the indices, since node that are not pointed to by any edge don't matter. We have to iterate over `set(G)` though to avoid repeating a start node that it pointed to by multiple other nodes.

```py
def c(G):
 u=0
 for i in set(G):
  j=i
  while j>=0:G[j],j=~i,G[j]
  u+=j==~i
 return u
```

Comment: Shortest Python code yet posted, and an interesting 'chalk marking' method.  I like it.