# Find the minimal initial values

Tags: code-golf, math, sequence, fibonacci

Consider a sequence `F` of positive integers where `F(n) = F(n-1) + F(n-2)` for `n >= 2`.  The Fibonacci sequence is *almost* one example of this type of sequence for `F(0) = 0, F(1) = 1`, but it's excluded because of the positive integer requirement.  Any two initial values will yield a different sequence.  For example `F(0) = 3, F(1) = 1` produces these terms.

```
3, 1, 4, 5, 9, 14, 23, 37, 60, 97, ...
```

#### Challenge

The task is to find `F(0)` and `F(1)` that minimize `F(0) + F(1)` given some term of a sequence `F(n)`.  Write a function or complete program to complete the task.

#### Input

Input is a single positive integer, `F(n)`.  It may be accepted as a parameter or from standard input.  Any reasonable representation is allowed, including direct integer or string representations.

Invalid inputs need not be considered.

#### Output

The output will be two positive integers, `F(0)` and `F(1)`.  Any reasonable format is acceptable.  Here are some examples of reasonable formats.

- Written on separate lines to standard output
- Formatted on standard output as a delimited 2-element list
- Returned as a tuple or 2-element array of integers from a function

#### Examples

```
60  -> [3, 1]
37  -> [3, 1]
13  -> [1, 1]
26  -> [2, 2]
4   -> [2, 1]
5   -> [1, 1]
6   -> [2, 2]
7   -> [2, 1]
12  -> [3, 2]
1   -> [1, 1]
```

#### Scoring

This is code golf.  The score is calculated by bytes of source code.

[Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/17030/527)

Comment: does `12 -> [4, 0]` count?

Comment: `F` is a sequence of positive integers, and 0 isn't positive, so that's not valid.

Comment: Nitpick: the Fibonacci sequence may be defined by \$F[0] = 0, F[1] = 1\$ or \$F[1] = F[2] = 1\$. Many of the sequence's well-known properties rely on this indexing.

Comment: @Dennis:  Technical correctness being the best kind, I've tweaked that part.

Comment: This feels familiar but, at the same time, I think the challenge I might be thinking of is the reverse of this - given `F(0)`, `F(1)` and `n` as input, output `F(n-1)+F(n-2)`.

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of [The lowest initial numbers in a Fibonacci-like sequence](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/147836/20260)

Comment: @xnor: Yes, I suppose it is.  Being the author isn't enough to close it though, but I voted for it.

Comment: I knew this challenge looked familiar but I couldn't find it. I've closed it, although I forgot that my vote was a hammer.

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 13 bytes

```
pWạ\Ṛ$</¿€SÞḢ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/78g/OGuhTEPd85SsdE/tP9R05rgw/Me7lj031pJ4XA7kKvg/v@/mYGOgrG5joKhsY6CkZmOgomOgqmOApABEjMCYgA)

#### How it works

```
pWạ\Ṛ$</¿€SÞḢ  Main link. Argument: n

 W             Wrap; yield [n].
p              Cartesian product; promote the left argument n to [1, ..., n] and take
               the product of [1, ..., n] and n, yielding [[1, n], ..., [n, n]].
         €     Map the link to the left over the pairs [k, n].
        ¿          While...
      </               reducing the pair by less-than yields 1:
  ạ\                       Cumulatively reduce the pair by absolute difference.
    Ṛ                      Reverse the result.
                   In essence, starting with [a, b] := [k, n], we keep executing
                   [a, b] := [b, |a - b|], until the pair is no longer increasing.
          SÞ   Sort the resulting pairs by their sums.
            Ḣ  Head; extract the first pair.
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 34 bytes

```
_Ì<U?[ZÌZx]gV:ZÌ
õ ïUõ)ñx æ_gV ¥U
```

[Try it online!](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.6&code=Cl/MPFU/W1rMWnhdZ1Y6WswK9SDvVfUp8XggZl9nViClVcNn&input=WzYwLAozNywKMTMsCjI2LAo0LAo1LAo2LAo3LAoxMiwKMV0KLVJt)

The empty first line is important.

Explanation:

```
_                     Declare a function V:
 Ì<U?        :ZÌ        If the second number is >= n, return it
     [ZÌZx]gV           Otherwise call V again with the second number and the sum


õ ïUõ)                Get all pairs of positive integers where both are less than n
      ñx              Sort them by their sum
         æ_gV ¥U      Return the first (lowest sum) one where V returns n
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 52 bytes

```perl6
->\n{(1..n X 1..n).max:{(n∈(|$_,*+*...*>n))/.sum}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYPtf1y4mr1rDUE8vTyFCAURp6uUmVlhVa@Q96ujQqFGJ19HS1tLT09Oyy9PU1NcrLs2trf1fnFipkKahEq@pkJZfpGBmoKNgbK6jYGiso2BkpqNgoqNgqqMAZIDEjID4PwA)

Brute-force solution.

Answer (score 1):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>81</s> 80 bytes

- -1 byte thanks to [Laikoni](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/56433/laikoni)

```hs
f x=[(a,s-a)|s<-[2..],a<-[1..s-1],let u=s-a:zipWith(+)u(a:u),x`elem`take x u]!!0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYuxCsMgFAD3foXZlL5ITFoLoX5C5w5BmjcYItEgVUFK/90Gut1x3IpxM87VupCiJooQW2TfeG@nnnMNeIDgPLZCgzOJZHX08WPD06aVnlmmOGYGZTbO@DnhZkghWTdNV@0ecopqkh0MNxAD9BIucAUJh/Ug9Mmj3ZXH8HjR8LZ74gv7T/UH)

Comment: `head[...]` can be `[...]!!0`.

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript, 216 bytes

```
function f(r){for(var n=1;;){var f=p(n);for(var u in f)if(s(f[u][0],f[u][1],r))return f[u];n++}}function p(r){for(var n=[],f=1;0<r;)n.push([r,f]),r--,f++;return n}function s(r,n,f){return n==f||(f<n?null:s(n,r+n,f))}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/twkz2gyb/

(Ungolfed code):

```
// For a given input n, return all combinations of positive integers that sum to n.
function findPairs(n) {
    var arr = [];
    var b = 1;
    while(n > 0) {
        arr.push([n, b]);
        n--;
        b++;
    }
    return arr;
}

// Run a sequence for a and b, and continue fibonacci'ing until r is found(or quit if past r).
function sequence(a, b, r) {
    if(b === r) {
        return true;
    } else if(b > r) {
        return null;
    }
    var nextFibo = a + b;
    return sequence(b, nextFibo, r);
}

// For a given n, find the first 2 numbers of the fibonacci sequence with the smallest sum that result in n.
function find(n) {
    var i = 1;
    while(i < 10) {
        var pairs = findPairs(i);
        for(var p in pairs) {
            var result = sequence(pairs[p][0], pairs[p][1], n);
            if(result) {
                return pairs[p];
            }
        }
        i++;
    }
}
```